# API call fails because of additional escape character in json

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, python-2.7

I am trying to make an API call to service running locally. The service expects post to have json data like this:

```
{"tool" : "name", "version" : "1", "payload" : "{"branch" : "main"}"
```

All these are member of a class where variables are all string (tool, version and payload) and I initialize them with respective strings: `"name", "version" and "{\"branch\" : \"main\"}"`
Now when I dump the class variable using `json.dumps(self.__dict__)`, I get following json, which I send to my api call:

```
json_upload = {"tool" : "name", "version" : "1", "payload" : "{\\"branch\\" : \\"main\\"}"
```

I added a line `json_upload.replace("\\\\", "\\")` but every time API call fails with 415 and I see the data sent to the api endpoint has double escape character. This is really frustrating, as I don't understand how to strip that extra `"\\"`. How do I fix this? I am using standard library json for encoding.

Comment: Have you tried `json_upload = {"tool" : "name", "version" : "1", "payload" : '{"branch" : "main"}'` (using single quotes for the `payload` value)?

Comment: What the server expects is not a valid json.

Comment: @pault I just tried that. Same result. API rejects it with 415. If I remove that extra escape character and send the same data through curl, it accepts it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like the data got escaped twice.

> Now when I dump the class variable using json.dumps(self.**dict**), I get following json, which I send to my api call:

Which client library are you using? e.g. with `requests` you just pass the object and it will be converted to JSON:

```
r = requests.post('http://example.com/post', json={"key": "value"})
```

And if you give it a string, it will escape the string.